# Disable SSL/TLS Renegotiation In Tomcat

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat7

This is regarding the SSL/TLS Renegotiation issue. We are using Tomcat 7.0.47 as our web server for our application.
I tried many different ways to disable the renegotiation, but couldn't succeed.
We enabled SSL as follows in Server.xml file:

```
<Connector SSLEnabled="true" 
           clientAuth="false" 
           compressableMimeType="text/html,text/plain,text/xml,text/css,text/javascript,image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg,application/json" 
           compression="on" 
           compressionMinSize="2048" 
           connectionTimeout="15000" 
           debug="0" 
           disableUploadTimeout="true" 
           enableLookups="false" 
           keyAlias="SomeAlias" 
           keystoreFile="C:\.keystore" 
           keystorePass="SomePassword" 
           maxHttpHeaderSize="20480" 
           maxSpareThreads="100" 
           maxThreads="400" 
           minSpareThreads="25" 
           port="8443"
           protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           allowUnsafeLegacyRenegotiation=false            
           scheme="https" 
           secure="true" 
           sslProtocol="TLS" 
           tomcatAuthentication="false"/>
```

Here, I tried setting the option **allowUnsafeLegacyRenegotiation=false** but server is not able to start with this setting.

Comment: Define 'not able to start'.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the **current** JSSE implementation from Oracle doesn't provide any solution to your problem. But you can run an old Java (Java 6 update 19/20/21) as it explained in the [JSSE Reference Guide table 7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#phased), since these versions called "phase 1 Fix" allowed to completely remove renegotiation support.

Considering that the old Java versions had other problems and you probably don't want to run them, the most secure is to only allow the newest renegotiations ([RFC 5746](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5746)). For this, as explained in [JSSE Reference Guide table 9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#phased), set these two system properties to false : allowLegacyHelloMessages , allowUnsafeRenegotiation.
And remove allowUnsafeLegacyRenegotiation connector attribute which is no more usefull.

Comment: Besides, if you're configuring for enhanced security, you should remove compression from your connector.

Comment: I set allowLegacyHelloMessages, allowUnsafeRenegotiation options to false. But still the issue exists.

Comment: how do you see this issue ? with a network capture ? If you're running a JConsole, please check the system properties at this place then we're sure they are taken in account.

Comment: I can see this issue from the response of the command 'openssl s_client -connect <HOST>:<port>'. The response contains "Secure Renegotiation IS supported". Basically what am trying to look is, I don't want the renegotiation at all.

Comment: Right, the settings I suggested only disable old fashion renegotiations. I rewrote my answer to explain that better. No renegotiation at all means running old Java, or giving bounties to look for advanced solutions that we can't promise by now as they need deep investigations.

Comment: @EugèneAdell thanks for your answer i am using java.lang.System.setProperty("sun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation", "false");  java.lang.System.setProperty("sun.security.ssl.allowLegacyHelloMessages", "false"); But , still i am getting Secure Renegotiation IS supported i am using springboot.